# Marshalling Variable Length Array in C#

Tags: c#, com, marshalling, hid, raw-input

I am processing input data from a human interface device using [GetRawInputData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645596(v=vs.85).aspx). There is a [RAWINPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645562(v=vs.85).aspx) structure which contains a RAWHID structure:

```
typedef struct tagRAWHID {
  DWORD dwSizeHid;
  DWORD dwCount;
  BYTE  bRawData[1];
} RAWHID, *PRAWHID, *LPRAWHID;
```

From the documentation:

> The size of the bRawData array is dwSizeHid *  dwCount.

The code for the structs are trivial (save RAWHID) so I will not include them.

The HID is a magnetic stripe reader, so depending on the number of tracks and their length, the size of bRawData changes.

I have a solution for my use case but I would like to do it the right way.

P/Invoke Signature:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetRawInputData(IntPtr hRawInput, DataCommand command, 
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pData, ref int size, int sizeHeader);
```

Calling GetInputData:

```
var dwSize = 0;
GetRawInputData(lParam, DataCommand.RID_INPUT, null, ref dwSize, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Rawinputheader)));
//dwSize is now the size of input data since pData was null
var data = new byte[dwSize];

if (dwSize != GetRawInputData(lParam, DataCommand.RID_INPUT, data, ref dwSize, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Rawinputheader))))
{
     //error occured
}
//turn it into a string
string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

I then regex the entire structure's data and pull out the tracks from the magnetic swipe since they have sentinel characters at the beginning and end. Is there a more elegant way to go about this?